# Admin order form - update custom area with ajax on add product

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, custom, prototype-js

I add custom field to admin order form and I want it to be updated with ajax when admin add products to order, like other areas - shipping, billing and totals. I inspected file `\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\web\order\create\scripts.js`. There is a function

```
productGridAddSelected : function(){
        if(this.productGridShowButton) Element.show(this.productGridShowButton);
        var area = ['search', 'items', 'shipping_method', 'totals', 'giftmessage','billing_method'];
        ...
```

When I add my custom area name to it, like this, it works!

```
var area = ['custom_area', 'search', 'items', 'shipping_method','totals', 'giftmessage','billing_method'];....
```

But this is core file, so I need to do this somehow in my module. Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this js script to my html block template

```
if (typeof(order) != 'undefined') {
   order.prepareArea = function(area) {
        if (this.giftMessageDataChanged) {
            return area.without('giftmessage');
        }
        if(order.getAreaId('store_credit')) area.push("store_credit");
        return area;
    };
}
```

So basically I rewrite prepareArea function from  AdminOrder class and add here my area. That's it